# Prompt for password when postgres client reconnects after session timeout

Tags: postgresql, security, timeout

I am using postgres client to invoke postgres on the command line:

```
./bin/postgres -U user db_name
```

This prompts user to enter the password.
How can I set a timeout to the user's session?

Answer (score 0):

There is no session timeout feature in `psql`, nor in the server-side `postgres` server. It's a good idea, and you should feel free to suggest adding it on pgsql-general and ask if someone wants to add it to the TODO list. Or try your hand at implementing it.

If you're on PostgreSQL 9.3 or newer so you have the `state_change` field in the `pg_stat_activity` system view, you could fairly easily implement a cron job, server-side, that scans for idle connections and calls `pg_terminate_backend` on them. Note that this would terminate any running transaction and would clear any user `SET` variables, `WITH HOLD` cursors, advisory locks, etc, because it force-disconnects the user.

Comment: Thanks for the details. But my idea if there was any timeouts for interactive sessions i.e. the command line from security PoV. I have implemented a similar thing in mysql which has changes in my.cnf and mysql client settings.

Comment: @mohanjot There isn't, but it's a good idea. Please feel free to submit a patch to pgsql-hackers@postgresql.org and then put the patch on the open commitfest at https://commitfest.postgresql.org/ for tracking. You'll want to add a psql variable (akin to `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK` or `FETCH_COUNT`) and/or an environment variable, probably. Or pay someone to develop it; see http://www.postgresql.org/support/professional_support/ . The patch would pretty simple; shepherding it through the commitfest and into core, less so. I'll take a look if I get a chance but it won't be soon.

Comment: @mohanjot Note, though, that unless your changes cause the client to de-authenticate with the server and overwrite the password in memory, I bet I could exploit your locked `mysql` session with `gdb` to gain access and/or recover the credentials. No root required either, just control-Z out of the `mysql` session and `gdb -p $(jobs -p)`. PostgreSQL doesn't have the concept of de-authenticating a session without closing it (might be worth proposing for the v4 protocol TODO) so your lock wouldn't be secure against a determined attacker. (They could also use `LD_PRELOAD` attacks)